# WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, bin does not persist

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, fish

I'm setting up a dev environment, however I have a problem with my shell:
I added those lines to the end of ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc files:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/neovim/nvim-linux64/bin/"

set PATH $PATH:/usr/local/neovim/nvim-linux64/bin
```

however, the command "nvim" is still not recognizable when starting a new shell session (after exiting the previous one) so each time i log in I have to use:

```
set PATH $PATH:/usr/local/neovim/nvim-linux64/bin
```

over and over again (I'm using fish)

Any ideas on how to solve this issue? How can i "Set" the binaries to always be added and be available from the terminal anywhere?

Comment: [How to edit the fish shell startup script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/211519/174496)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I added those lines to the end of ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc files:

Fish does not read these files. It's not bash, so it doesn't read bashrc, and it's not posix-compatible, so it does not read profile.

The equivalent to these files is ~/.config/fish/config.fish, so the equivalent of what you have been doing in bash is to stick your `set PATH $PATH /usr/local/neovim/nvim-linux64/bin` into that file. You want a space, not a `:`.

---

Alternatively, fish knows persistent variables known as "universal" variables. You can use these. For $PATH it has a helper called `fish_add_path`. Run

```
fish_add_path /usr/local/neovim/nvim-linux64/bin
```

once, interactively, and it should persist that that path should be added to $PATH on every startup. You can also stick it in config.fish if you want.

Comment: Thank you, There's one thing i don't understand however.
On my mac machine (I assume zsh is used there) all of the links/bin additions are added to bashrc (or some equivalent of config), however they still 'transfer' over to fish when used. (In other words, on my other machine there was no need for config.fish file) how come?

Comment: Two possibilities: 1. mac has /etc/paths, which fish also reads (because it's just a list of paths), 2. if the shell is started somewhere in the startup path, and so fish is a child (directly or indirectly), the variables will just be inherited

Comment: Thank you, Is there a way to set up fish in the case of mine to inherit those configs as you mentioned?